# spark - how to look up the keys and values of a (Java)PairRDD inside another RDD's transformation

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a PairRDD `rdd1` with Integer keys and Integer[] values.

I also have another PairRDD `rdd2` with Integer keys and Double values.

Each Integer in the key AND the value of `rdd1` also exists in `rdd2` as a key.

I want for each pair `(x, [y1,y2,...,yn])` in `rdd1` to get the double value of the `x` and all the double values of each Integer `y1`, `y2`, ..., `yn`.

I tried collecting `rdd2` as a `Map<Integer,Double>` (`map2`), but it does not fit in memory and I get OOM errors. I also tried joining the rdds, but I could not figure out how to join both the keys and the values. Using `rdd2`'s `lookup()` method inside `rdd1` is not allowed.

The pseudocode of what I want is the following:

```
map each (int x, int[] y) in rdd1 to:
      (x, map2.get(x) + sum(map2.get(yi)))
```

for each `yi` in `y`.

I use Java, but I guess the same problem holds in both Java and Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with missing matches (cases where there's an index in `rdd1` and no corresponding index in `rdd2`), the query looks something like the following.

```
rdd1.
    // ( x, [ y1, ..., yn ] ) -> ( x, x ), ( y1, x ), ..., ( yn, x )
    flatMap { case ( x, ys ) => ( x :: ys ).map( ( _, x ) ) }.
    // ( xory, x ) -> ( xory, ( x, rdd2.lookup( xory ) ) )
    leftOuterJoin( rdd2 ).
    // ( xory, ( x, rdd2.lookup( xory ) ) ) -> ( x, rdd2.lookup( xory ) )
    map( _._2 ).
    // ( x, rdd2.lookup( x ) ), ... -> ( x, rdd2.lookup( x ) + sum_i( rdd2.lookup( y_i ) )
    reduceByKey{ case ( dopt1, dopt2 ) => ( dopt1 ++ dopt2 ).reduceOption( _ + _ ) }.
    // unwrap the option types
    mapValues( _.getOrElse( 0.0 ) )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1,asList(2,3));
    map.put(3,asList(4,5));

    System.out.println(
            map.entrySet().stream()
                    .flatMap(kv -> 
                            Stream.concat(
                                    Stream.of((double)kv.getKey()),
                                    kv.getValue().stream().mapToDouble( x -> Double.valueOf((double)x) ).boxed())
                    )
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
```

How about this? ... should give you all (keys and values) in one RDD which you can use as keys in your second RDD. You can of course change the type.